# google app engine TLS 1.2 Support

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, tls1.2

I am using Google App Engine Dev Server(1.9.36) and JDK 1.7 .

I am connecting with SalesForce using `URLFetchServiceFactory`:

```
FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.validateCertificate();
fetchOptions.setDeadline(20.00);

HTTPRequest post = new HTTPRequest(new URL(SalesforceAPI.getRequestUrl()), HTTPMethod.POST, fetchOptions);
post.addHeader(ACCEPT_APPLICATION_JSON);
post.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
post.setPayload(payload.getBytes(Utils.UTF_8_CHARSET));

HTTPResponse resp = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(post);
```

But recently SalesForce stopped supporting TLS 1.0, so this is not working on Dev Server, I migrated to JDK 1.8 also but it's still not working.

Comment: Please format code as such.